# Classification with labels as feature input

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

Suppose I have 100 different labels in the form of the numbers 1 to 100 and the following data. A list of triples, where a triple has the following meaning: (a,b,c) means that the label a is more similar to b than to c. If the triplet (a,b,c) is given, I can conclude directly that (a,c,b) is "false".

Now I want to predict for an unknown triple if it is true. For example (x,y,z) should be classified as 1, if x is more similar to y than to z. Otherwise it should be classified as 0. What could be a suitable classifier for this problem?

*(Where a,b,c,x,y,z are integers from 1 to 100 - representing the different labels)

Comment: So these a,b,c... are actually a categorical variable represented as an integer, right? So, could this be a product name for instance? Just trying to get the intuition.

Comment: If so, an initial baseline could be to one-hot encode each triplet, assign the label of 1 or 0 and using the concatenated one-hot representation train any supervised model to predict the 1 or 0. You could also use embeddings with neural nets instead of one-hot.

Comment: @Stergios Yes, your assumption is correct.

Comment: Does my proposed approach make sense to you?